# I am confused when using Apache POI 5.2.5 to get table height in Power Point slide

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

My scenario is that I have a dynamically text frame in a Power Point slide, the text frame will be replaced by a table and the table height must be less than or equal to text frame height.

My steps are following:

1. get text frame height and anchor
2. create a table to replace the text frame by anchor
3. add rows to the table until the table height is greater than text frame height
4. if table height is greater than text frame height, I will remove the last row then add the removed row to next slide table.

My code is here

```
  private static void genSlide(XSLFSlide slide, int startIndex, List<Map<String, Object>> newSpecMapList, XMLSlideShow ppt, Rectangle2D textShapAnchor){
    System.out.println("textShapAnchor: " + textShapAnchor);
    if (startIndex > newSpecMapList.size() - 1){
      return;
    }
    for (XSLFShape shape: slide){
      if (shape instanceof XSLFTable){
        XSLFTable table = (XSLFTable) shape;
        if (table.getRows().size() > 0){
          for (int i = table.getRows().size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            System.out.println("row: " + table.getRows().get(i));
            table.removeRow(i);
          }
          table.updateCellAnchor();
        }
        double totalRowsHeight = 0.0;
        double totalCellsHeight = 0.0;
        for (int i = startIndex; i < newSpecMapList.size(); i++){
          System.out.println(newSpecMapList.get(i));
          XSLFTableRow row = table.addRow();
          XSLFTableCell columnNameCell = row.addCell();
          XSLFTableCell columnValueCell = row.addCell();
          setCellTextStyle(columnNameCell, newSpecMapList.get(i).get("FIELD").toString(), true);
          setCellTextStyle(columnValueCell, newSpecMapList.get(i).get("VALUE").toString(), true);
          setTableProperty(slide, textShapAnchor);
          table.updateCellAnchor();
          totalRowsHeight += table.getRowHeight(i - startIndex);
          totalCellsHeight += table.getRows().get(i - startIndex).getHeight();
          System.out.println("After set borders for table height: " + table.getAnchor().getHeight());
          if (i == newSpecMapList.size() - 1){
            if (startIndex == 0){
              setTableBorders(table,true, startIndex);
            }
            else {
              setTableBorders(table,false, startIndex);
            }
            System.out.println("finally table anchor: " + table.getAnchor());
            table.updateCellAnchor();
          }
          if (table.getAnchor().getHeight() > textShapAnchor.getHeight()){
//          if (totalRowsHeight > textShapAnchor.getHeight()){
            System.out.println("table height: " + table.getAnchor().getHeight());
            System.out.println("table all rows height: " + totalRowsHeight);
            System.out.println("table all cells height: " + totalCellsHeight);
            table.removeRow(table.getRows().size() - 1);
            table.updateCellAnchor();
            if (startIndex == 0){
              setTableBorders(table,true, startIndex);
            }
            else {
              setTableBorders(table,false, startIndex);
            }
            table.updateCellAnchor();
            System.out.println("table anchor: " + table.getAnchor());
            XSLFSlide nextSlide = copySlide(slide, ppt);
            System.out.println("New line index: " + i);
            genSlide(nextSlide, i, newSpecMapList, ppt, textShapAnchor);
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
  private static void setTableProperty(XSLFSlide slide, Rectangle2D textShapeAnchor){
    for (XSLFShape shape : slide){
      if(shape instanceof XSLFTable){
        XSLFTable slideTable = (XSLFTable) shape;
        slideTable.setColumnWidth(0, textShapeAnchor.getWidth() * 0.3);
        slideTable.setColumnWidth(1, textShapeAnchor.getWidth() * 0.7);
        slideTable.updateCellAnchor();
      }
    }
  }
```

```
  private static XSLFSlide copySlide(XSLFSlide slide, XMLSlideShow ppt){
    XSLFSlideMaster srcMaster = ppt.getSlideMasters().get(0);
    XSLFSlideLayout slidelayout = srcMaster.getSlideLayouts()[1];
    XSLFSlide newSlide = slide.getSlideShow().createSlide(slidelayout);
    newSlide.importContent(slide);
    return newSlide;
  }
```

```
  private static void setTableBorders(XSLFTable table, boolean isTitle, int startIndex) {
    for (int i=0;i<table.getNumberOfRows();i++){
      XSLFTableRow row = table.getRows().get(i);
      for (XSLFTableCell cell : row.getCells()) {
        if(0==i && isTitle){
          //set background color black
          cell.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
          //set text color white
          cell.getTextParagraphs().get(i).getTextRuns().get(i).setFontColor(Color.white);
          cell.getTextParagraphs().get(i).getTextRuns().get(i).setBold(true);
        }else if(1==((i + startIndex) %2)){
          //set background color white
          cell.setFillColor(Color.white);
        }else{
          //set background color gray
          cell.setFillColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }
        XSLFTableCell.BorderEdge[] edges = XSLFTableCell.BorderEdge.values();
        for (XSLFTableCell.BorderEdge edge : edges) {
          cell.setBorderColor(edge, Color.BLACK);
          cell.setBorderWidth(edge, borderWidth);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

to get text frame height. I often find the table show more rows than text frame range or show less 2 rows than text frame but the table getHeight() value is less than text frame getHeight() value.

Does anyone have the same problem?

I try to use another way to sum every rows height to calculate, but the solution have the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.  You should add specific examples and the relevant code.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. 
Also read 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: Have you tried using [XSLFTable.updateCellAnchor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTable.html#updateCellAnchor--) after manipulating the table and before trying to get the height from the anchor? Apache POI will not correct anchor dimensions automatically while manipulsting the table.

Comment: Yes, I use updateCellAnchor everytime after my table is added rows. thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter. I have a question it seems not accurate to get table anchor height after I use setColumnWidth() on table columns. Sometimes table will over the limitation height although the table anchor height is less than limitation height . Do you have this experience?

Comment: No, I don't have this experience. But I decided not to trust any of the [DrawFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/sl/draw/DrawFactory.html) classes using `java.awt.Graphics` because it always will be inaccurate because of to much differences to Microsoft Windows own drawing. A reliable solution is having all table rows the same format (same height). Then you can simply count how much of such rows fit into given shape-height of slide. If that count is reached, you need a new slide.

Comment: @AxelRichter, thanks for your advice. But I can not set fixed row height because cells may include wrapped text over one row and others may include \n\r in the cell. Even if I set fixed row height, the above situation will make row height changed.

I also try to calculate table getheight(), row getheight() and text getheight(). It seems table getHeight() is more accurate than others, but sometimes it also not accurate.